# Specialized shouldComponentUpdate on PureComponent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a component that shouldn't when a certain property is true, but should perform a shallow compare (the default for `PureComponent`).

I've tried doing the following behavior:

```
export default class ContentsListView extends PureComponent<Props> {
  shouldComponentUpdate(props: Props) {
    if (props.selecting) {
      return false;
    }
    return super.shouldComponentUpdate(props);
  }

  render() {
  }
}
```

However, `super.shouldComponentUpdate` is not defined. Is there some way to "tap into" the shallow compare of `PureComponent` without writing my own?

Comment: did you ever find a way to do this, I too would like the default behaviour of a PureComponent, with one additional check on a particular prop?

Answer (score 9):

You should not implement `shouldComponentUpdate` when you are extending your component using `PureComponent`. If however you want to use the shouldComponentUpdate functionality you can simply write a wrapper component around your original component or use HOC to implement your custom `shouldComponentUpdate` and render the PureComponent

Sample code

```
class ContentsListView extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    console.log("render list");
    return (
      ...
    );
  }
}

export default class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(props) {
    if (props.selecting) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  render() {
    return <ContentsListView {...this.props} />;
  }
}
```

You can see a working demo on **[codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/xlxy79q39w)**

Answer (score 7):

There is no `super.shouldComponentUpdate` in `PureComponent` because it implements shallow checks by checking [`isPureReactComponent` property](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v16.8.6/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberClassComponent.js#L273-L277), not with `shouldComponentUpdate`. A warning is issued when both `isPureReactComponent` and `shouldComponentUpdate` are in use because `shouldComponentUpdate` efficiently overrides the behaviour of `isPureReactComponent`.

React doesn't expose its `shallowEqual` implementation, third-party implementation should be used.

In case this becomes a common task, own `PureComponent` implementation can be used for extension:

```
import shallowequal from 'shallowequal';

class MyPureComponent extends Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(props, state) {
    if (arguments.length < 2)
      throw new Error('Do not mess super arguments up');

    return !shallowequal(props, this.props) || !shallowequal(state, this.state);
  }
}

class Foo extends MyPureComponent {
  shouldComponentUpdate(props, state) {
    if (props.selecting) {
      return false;
    }
    return super.shouldComponentUpdate(props, state);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can consider writing your component in a function instead of class, try `React.memo`.

> React.memo is a higher order component. It’s similar to React.PureComponent but for function components instead of classes.
>
> If your function component renders the same result given the same props, you can wrap it in a call to React.memo for a performance boost in some cases by memoizing the result. This means that React will skip rendering the component, and reuse the last rendered result.
>
> By default it will only shallowly compare complex objects in the props object. If you want control over the comparison, you can also provide a custom comparison function as the second argument.

As a second argument, you can pass a function, where you can use `prevProps, nextProps`, and return false, if you want it to render, or return true if you don't.

```
import React, { memo } from "react";

const ContentsListView = ({ selecting }) => {
  return <div />;
};

const shouldComponentUpdate = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  if (nextProps.selecting) { return true; }
  return JSON.stringify(prevProps) === JSON.stringify(nextProps)
}

const Component = memo(ContentsListView, shouldComponentUpdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing as you can see from my comment in January, I had eventually settled on using the `shallow-compare` library - https://www.npmjs.com/package/shallow-compare

```
export default class ContentsListView extends Component<Props> {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (props.selecting) {
      return false;
    }
    return shallowCompare(this, nextProps, nextState);
  }

  render() {
  }
}
```

however extend from Component, not PureComponent